# Regarding to the ace editor, how to monitor the characters entered by the user

Tags: vue.js, ace-editor

[Event monitor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8cJBw.png)

Regarding to the ace editor, how to monitor the characters entered by the user, I did not find the keydown event monitor for the ace editor. Is there any way to get the character entered by the user using the keyboard?

Comment: https://ace.c9.io/build/kitchen-sink.html see this

Comment: there are several ways e.g. change event or exec event on editor.commands, but to give a more useful answer i would need more information about what you want to do by monitoring.

Comment: I manually bound the keyup method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved this problem.Use manual binding keyup events.